# Tkinter window items (widgets) not showing up even after using pack. (Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a program called PythOS Pro, the successor to [PythOS](https://www.github.com/Captain-Awesome-Jnr/PythOS) which I recently created. It is a package to add a graphical user interface to PythOS (which only uses a text shell) and it is in development. I had imported tkinter and decided to create a window that said 'Welcome to PythOS Pro'  and the window worked. I then tried adding text in and, even after using `pack`, it did not show up!

This is the program's code:

```
import tkinter as tk
def run():
    print("Importing packages. Please wait...")
    import time
    import random
    time.sleep(2)
    print("PythOS Pro is being deployed. Please wait...")
    time.sleep(1)
    StartSuccsess = random.randint(0, 100)
    if StartSuccsess == 0:
        print("""An error has occured. The system has halted. Please refer to the PythOS Pro error page on GitHub.
发生错误。系统已停止。请参考 GitHub 上的 PythOS Pro 错误页面。
Произошла ошибка. Система остановилась. Пожалуйста, обратитесь к странице ошибок PythOS Pro на GitHub.
Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Das System wurde angehalten. Weitere Informationen finden Sie auf der Fehlerseite von PythOS Pro auf GitHub.

Error Code / 错误代码 / Код ошибки / Fehlercode: E0006""")
    else:
        time.sleep(4)
        main()

def main():
    print("SUCCESS") # This is a placeholder. When finished, the core of PythOS Pro will be here!
    Main = tk.Tk
    WelcomeText = tk.Label(text="Welcome to PythOS Pro!")
    WelcomeText.pack

run() # This will be for dev testing because it is tested standalone.
```

I know questions like this have been asked but I have used tkinter before and it worked, so I am EXTREMLY CONFUSED!

---

I tried using online code but even that did not work. My version of Python is 3.10.2, released on January 13 2022 (yes, a year ago!) I also tried the latest Visual Studio Code but it has no tkinter support.

I was expecting for the text to show up and then have a party sending it on to GitHub!!!

Comment: It should be `WelcomeText.pack()` instead.

Comment: It should also be `Main = tk.Tk()`

Answer (score 0):

`mainloop` will keep the window open, also `()` must be included in `Tk()`

```
import tkinter as tk
def run():
    print("Importing packages. Please wait...")
    import time
    import random
    time.sleep(2)
    print("PythOS Pro is being deployed. Please wait...")
    time.sleep(1)
    StartSuccsess = random.randint(0, 100)
    if StartSuccsess == 0:
        print("""An error has occured. The system has halted. Please refer to the 
PythOS Pro error page on GitHub.
发生错误。系统已停止。请参考 GitHub 上的 PythOS Pro 错误页面。
Произошла ошибка. Система остановилась. Пожалуйста, обратитесь к странице 
ошибок PythOS Pro на GitHub.
Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Das System wurde angehalten. Weitere 
Informationen finden Sie auf der Fehlerseite von PythOS Pro auf GitHub.

Error Code / 错误代码 / Код ошибки / Fehlercode: E0006""")
    else:
        time.sleep(4)
        main()

def main():
    print("SUCCESS") # This is a placeholder. When finished, the core of PythOS Pro will be here!
    mainwindow = tk.Tk()
    mainwindow.title('Welcome Text')
    button = tk.Label(text='Welcome to PythOS Pro!')
    button.pack()
    mainwindow.mainloop()

run() # This will be for dev testing because it is tested standalone.
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: you're missing brace bracket at the end of `.pack`.

Change this:

```
WelcomeText.pack
```

to:

```
WelcomeText.pack()
```

Screenshot:

[image]